# FB Graph API - Successful scheduled publication is not displayed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I'm trying to program a personal-use application using FB Graph API in order to automate some recurrent publications on my own page. I made a successful post request that returned the id of the publication and I see the publication on my page feed but despite the publication has public access, I'm the only one that can see it. Anyone know what happen here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please show us your code?

Comment: afaik posts are only visible to users with a role in the app if the app is not public.

Comment: postPub = {
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/me/feed',
    options: {
      method: 'post',
      payload: {
        message: text,
        link: linkUrl,
        attached_media: photoId,
        published: false,
        scheduled_publish_time: unixDate,
        access_token: accessToken
      }
    }
  };
  
  postPubResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(postPub.url, postPub.options).getContentText();